# Find a string in a list of strings in c#

Tags: c#, string, list

I am trying to find if a list of strings contains a specific string in C#.
for example: Suppose I have 3 entries in my list

```
list<string> s1 = new List<string>(){
  "the lazy boy went to the market in a car", 
  "tom", 
  "balloon"};
string s2 = "market";
```

Now I want to return true if s1 contains s2, which it does in this case.

```
return s1.Contains(s2);
```

This returns false which is not what I want. I was reading about Predicate but could not make much sense out of it for this case.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The simplest way is to search each string individually:

```
bool exists = s1.Any(s => s.Contains(s2));
```

The `List<string>.Contains()` method is going to check if any *whole* string matches the string you ask for. You need to check each individual list element to accomplish what you want.

Note that this may be a time-consuming operation, if your list has a large number of elements in it, very long strings, and especially in the case where the string you're searching for either does not exist or is found only near the end of the list.

Comment: One note on it being a time consuming operation, `.Any(` will stop processing after the first `true` is returned so in the OP's example it only called Contains on the first string. Also for large lists this is a good case to use `AsParallel()` to split up the search across multiple threads `bool exists = s1.AsParallel().Any(s => s.Contains(s2));`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: exactly. That's why I qualified my comment by "large number of elements" or "long strings", and wrote "especially in the case where the string you're searching for...is found only near the end of the list". The performance is dependent on how much data there is to deal with, and how early the expensive iteration can terminate. In the example given, it doesn't matter at all; even if the string wasn't found at all, there's not enough data to notice the cost. A _real world_ example could be quite different. And yes, concurrency can help, if you've got the CPU cores to spare.

Comment: And to explain the `Predicate<>` question, while `Any<>` is a Linq method, where the lambda arrow is typed as a `Func<string, bool>` in this case, the `List<>` class also has an older `Exists` instance method where the same arrow gets the type `Predicate<string>`. Before the `Func<,>` delegate type was introduced, less general delegate types were used depending on context.

Comment: how about: s1.Where(s => s.IndexOf(s2, StringComparision.Ordinal) != -1)
This returns you the list of items that matches with s2

Answer (score 2):

Contains' alternative could be IndexOf:

```
var res = s1.Any(s => s.IndexOf(s2, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
```

StringComparison.Ordinal passed as parameter because Contains() also use it internally.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Duniho's answer is generally the best way. I am providing an alternate solution. This one does not require LINQ, lamdas, or loops. This only requires `string` built-in type's methods.

```
string.Concat(listOfString).Contains("data");
```

Note: This approach can lead to incorrect results. For example:

```
string.Concat("da", "ta").Contains("data");
```

will return true when it should be false;

Comment: If you do this with Join instead and specify a delimiter you could reduce the risk of those incorrect results you mention