# Find a string in a list of strings with reflection

Tags: c#, string, linq, reflection

```
List<string> typesList = new List<string>();
typesList.Add("product");
typesList.Add("valueType");
typesList.Add("categoryType");

foreach (var prop in someType.GetProperties())
{
    string filterValue = Filter.SecondStringByProp(prop, filterList, "_");//this return `valueType`

    bool wtf1 = typesList.Any(x => x == prop.Name.ToLower());
    bool wtf2 = typesList.Contains(prop.Name.ToLower());
    var wtf3 = typesList.Where(x => x == prop.Name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
    bool wtf4 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(typesList.Where(x => x == prop.Name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault());
    bool wtf5 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(typesList.Where(x => x == prop.Name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault());
    bool wtf6 = typesList.Any(s => s.Contains(prop.Name.ToLower()));
}
```

[answer that always work but not now!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574933/find-a-string-in-a-list-of-strings-in-c-sharp)

I do not understand why so many different ways that I think should work DO NOT WORK - to return `bool`

the above code is checking if `prop.Name.ToLower()` which is `valueType` is equal to element from collection `typesList` (`valueType`)

`wtf1` and `wtf2` - just for testing purpose and curiosity 
`wtf4` and `wtf5` - this just return the expected value
`wtf6` - wtf why return false?!

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with case sensitivity. Some of your types have capital letters.

Comment: Are your properties public?

Comment: If you are serious about this question, get a full reproducible example

Comment: I think it might work better if you variables didn't follow the naming convention of what the ****.

Comment: `.ToLower ()` - hahaha, I was so sure that the lower one only makes the first letter small! I deserve a minus! - I'm working too much, or I'm too distracted - at least it was funny :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> wtf why return false?!

have a look at your value:

```
typesList.Add("valueType");
```

if you stomp all the letters in your property name down to lower case then it will not match anymore!

```
typesList.Add("valueType");
                    ^
                    |
               //this is the difference
```

You need also to compare with an entry that is as well stomped into lower case:

```
bool wtf1 = typesList.Any(x => x.ToLowerInvariant() == prop.Name.ToLower());
```

returns: `true`

the same holds of course for the rest of the comparisons like the last one:

```
bool wtf6 = typesList.Any(s => s.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(prop.Name.ToLower()));
```

May be a better option would be to use string.Equals in connection with a compare option:

```
var wtf3 = typesList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(prop.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: `.ToLower ()` - hahaha, I was so sure that the lower one only makes the first letter small! I deserve a minus!

Comment: @szkut you're welcome. Next time you can have a look at [the example in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=netframework-4.8) ;) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Does it work more like you're expecting when you use lowercase `t` in your typesList items?

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FindAStringInAListOfStringsWithReflection
{
    class someType
    {
        public string CategoryType { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string ValueType { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> typesList = new List<string>();
            typesList.Add("product");
            typesList.Add("valuetype");
            typesList.Add("categorytype");

            foreach (var prop in typeof(someType).GetProperties())
            {
                bool wtf1 = typesList.Any(x => x == prop.Name.ToLower());
                bool wtf2 = typesList.Contains(prop.Name.ToLower());
                var wtf3 = typesList.Where(x => x == prop.Name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
                bool wtf4 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(typesList.Where(x => x == prop.Name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault());
                bool wtf5 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(typesList.Where(x => x == prop.Name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault());
                bool wtf6 = typesList.Any(s => s.Contains(prop.Name.ToLower()));
                //Debugging breakpoint on next line...
                bool pause = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```